# How can AVCaptureDevice device be called in swift

Tags: swift

I working in swiftui, swift 5+, Xcode Version 13.2.1. I am trying to programmatically request permission for camera usage using the code below
but I keep getting the error

> Cannot find 'AVCaptureDevice' in scope

here is my code

```
struct StartZoomVC: UIViewControllerRepresentable {

....

    func askPermissionsForCameraFeed() {

        
        switch AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: .video) {
            case .authorized: // The user has previously granted access to the camera.
                self.setupCaptureSession()
            
            case .notDetermined: // The user has not yet been asked for camera access.
                AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: .video) { granted in
                    if granted {
                        self.setupCaptureSession()
                    }
                }
            
            case .denied: // The user has previously denied access.
                return

            case .restricted: // The user can't grant access due to restrictions.
                return
        }
    }
```

i have researched what could be causing but no answer

Comment: Do you have `import AVFoundation` at the top of your file? Note that you probably want to do request access before checking the status: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624584-requestaccess

Comment: @jnpdx . Thank you. That was what was missing. I have fixed it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`AVCaptureDevice` is part of `AVFoundation`, so you'll need:

```
import AVFoundation
```

Note that you probably want to do request access before checking the status: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624584-requestaccess